# Hover Indicate selection with Jquery hover event

Tags: jquery, hover

I have this code to highlight any element if hovered on:

```
$('*').hover(function() {
  $(this).addClass('over'); 
}, function() {
  $(this).removeClass('over');
});
```

The problem is that all elements around my selection will also be highlighted. Take a look at the example: [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mtHyF/1/) Try to hover on the `span`, you will see the `p` and `body/html` are being highlighted as well.

What do I have to change in order to heighlight only the part Im hovering?

ps I have to use `*` because I dont know what the attributes are.

Comment: Why don't you do this with CSS?

Comment: It's hard to imagine when this would be useful. You can use `:hover` in CSS and as a jQuery selector.

Comment: @Blender Im designing some aplication, I dont know what the attributes are in advance, thats why the *

Comment: This is a really bad idea, but something like this [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/mtHyF/4/) ???

Comment: @Youss: No, I mean why are you doing this with jQuery in the first place?

Comment: do you want the small box to turn pink when you hover on the body?

Comment: @Blender Because I dont know how to do it in CSS, please show me...(I think you might have misread the question..)

Comment: @adeneo That seems to work but not as 'smooth' as the codes in the anwsers below (thanks anyway)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('*').hover(function(e) {
  $('*').removeClass('over');
  $(this).addClass('over');
  e.stopPropagation();

}, function() {
  $(this).parent().addClass('over');
  $(this).removeClass('over');
});
```

[`stopPropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) prevents the hover event from bubbling up the DOM, so in case your elements are flush left to the body, it will select the correct element (try entering from the top left to see what I mean).

See [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mtHyF/13/).

Comment: stopPropagation() is awsome:) To bad it reacts a bit to slow

Answer (score 2):

Remove the 'over' class from all elements before applying it to the newly hovered element:

```
$('*').hover(function() {
    $('*').removeClass('over');
    $(this).addClass('over'); 
    return false;
}, function() {
  $(this).removeClass('over');
  $(this).parent().addClass('over');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mtHyF/12/

Comment: This looks good, do you have any idea why the body is not getting selected when moving from `p` to `body` ?

Comment: @Youss hmm, no. My guess is because the mouse over function is not being called again because technically the mouse has always been over that element.

Comment: Thank yo +1 But I realy like stopPropagation() Zakang

Comment: @Youss You can also use `return false;` That fixes the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Remember, if you're inside an object, you're usually inside it's parent, and parent's parent, etc.  That's why you're getting multiple "over" objects.

If you only want innermost things to highlight, you could try:

```
if($(this).children().length==0) {
  $(this).addClass('over'); 
}
```

This would refuse to highlight anything with other objects inside it.

If you want the innermost object currently hovering (and neither its parents nor children), maybe:

```
$('*').hover(function() {
  $('*').removeClass('over'); 
  $(this).addClass('over'); 
}, function() {
  $(this).removeClass('over');
  $(this).parent().addClass('over');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you still want one element highlighted at all times, but if you're in an inner element you don't want its parent elements to be highlighted.  The following will accomplish that:

```
$('*').hover(function() {
    if ($(this).parent() != null)
    {
        $(this).parents().removeClass('over');
    }
    $(this).addClass('over'); 
}, function() {
    $(this).removeClass('over');
    $(this).parent().addClass('over');
});
```