# How to set style to this element

Tags: jquery

I have this script to set box-shadow if element is hovered. It should also remove the parent(s) style at the same time:

```
  var on = {
    boxShadow : "inset 0px 0px 0px 1px  #f80"
  };

  var out = {
    boxShadow : "inset 0px 0px 0px 0px  #f80"
  };

$('body *').hover(function(e) {
  $(this).css(out);
  $(this).css(on); 
  e.stopPropagation();
}, function() {
  $(this).parent().css(out);
  $(this).css(out);
});
```

If you look at this example [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mtHyF/14/) you will see that if you hover the span its parent (p) will also gain the style. What can I do to style only the element that is being hovered, so not its child nor its parent? Do I have to use each() ?

Comment: Im working on something much bigger in which I need body*

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hover Indicate selection with Jquery hover event](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15418904/hover-indicate-selection-with-jquery-hover-event). Does the answer you accepted as solving the problem not work correctly?

Comment: @Juhana It works of course but when I remove events `addClass/removeClass` and replace them with `.css` then the whole thing doesn't work. So Im wondering why that is, hence my question

Comment: Using the asterix as a selector, and applying mouseenter/leave to every single element on the page will cause you so must grief that you'll never be able to get to this to work properly.

Comment: If I use `.on` then I wouldn't be applying mouseenter/leave to all elements

Comment: `hover()` is just a shortcut for `on('mouseenter')` etc. so it does'nt really matter what you use, as that's not the issue, binding the event handler to every single element on the page ***is***.

Comment: I disagree, you wouldn't be binding event handlers to every single element on the page if you use `on` only to the one in your function. If you do `mouseover/out or hover` you will be binding on page load. But I think you are referring to something else, but I still don't see the problem...

Comment: adeneo is correct. If your `JQuery` selector selects more than one element, than what you do with the selection is done to ALL items of the selection. If you write `$('*').hover();` then the hover events are added to every element on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Got it working thanks to God:

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mtHyF/17/)

```
  var on = { boxShadow : "inset 0px 0px 0px 1px  #f80" };

  var out = { boxShadow : "inset 0px 0px 0px 0px  #f80" };

$('body *').hover(function(e) {
    $(this).parents().css(out);
  $(this).css(on); 
  e.stopPropagation();
}, function() {
  $(this).parent().css(out);
  $(this).css(out);
    $(this).parent().css(on);
});
```

You see @adeneo there is no problem:)

Comment: What you're doing is changing the `CSS` for all the parents of the element that triggered the hover to `out` and changing the `CSS` for the element that triggered the hover to `on`. Also there is no reason to have the `e.stopPropagation()`. If you put this code on a full website, every element in the website will be affected.